# I can't find my backup for the cpanel in whm/cpanel

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, backups, management

**The Problem:**
I have made a complete backup from the cpanel for the whole home folder. I have placed this folder in the default home directory. Thereafter, i tried to restore this file from the WHM, but i couldn't find it. Does anyone know what causes such problems?

**Additional Details:**

1. I am the administrator of the cpanel and i have complete access to the reseller WHM.
2. Check more details below with images:

[image: The Location of the Backup File in the cPanel]

[image: No Backups were found in the WHM panel]

[image: An error message of cannot restore is printed down upon trying to search for available backups for the username "admin"]

Thanks in advance for your help! any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Point to note is that the restore method you are trying is actually used to "move" the account to another server. Follow @Randy's answer to "restore" on own server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't restore a backup of a User that already exists :(

If you have SSH

/scripts/restorepkg --force

If not, you have to terminate the account through WHM. Whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your backup file is under /home/admin/ directory. You need to move it to /home/ directory, then terminate the account before restore the backup.